# Improve program readability for logic over multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to apply some logic over multiple columns, but all I could do is just write it one at a time (and that's not python way).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Ticker':['S&P','Kospi','FTSE','DAX','Topix'],
    'P/E_Cur':[26,21,16,14,23],
    'P/E_lag_1yr':[22,14,28,31,18],
    'P/E_lag_2yr':[17,11,13,np.NaN,10],
    'P/E_lag_3yr':[np.NaN,np.NaN,12,14,15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Current P/E is at 4 yr high and current value has increased over 10% in past 3 years. If any of this condition is met Flag will be 1 else 0. But if any field of column is Null then flag should be Null as well. All I could write is manually write all code

```
c1 = df['P/E_Cur'].notnull() 
c2 = df['P/E_lag_1yr'].notnull()  
c3 = df['P/E_lag_2yr'].notnull() 
c4 = df['P/E_lag_3yr'].notnull()

c5 = df['P/E_Cur']>df['P/E_lag_1yr']
c6 = df['P/E_Cur']>df['P/E_lag_2yr']
c7 = df['P/E_Cur']>df['P/E_lag_3yr'] 
c8 = (df['P/E_Cur']/df['P/E_lag_3yr']-1)>0.1

df['P/E_flag'] = np.where(c1&c2&c3&c4,np.where(c5&c6&c7&c8,1,0), np.NaN)
```

I want to write all this logic in python(smart) way.

Comment: Just a small comment... it is better to not mix var names. Here you use data for both the data and the dataframe (which normally uses variable name df). I'll change it if you dont mind.

Comment: Thanks. It actually makes more sense. I'll try to keep this in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt using [`pd.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html). Setting `axis=1` ensures we aggregate *over columns* or *by row*.

```
mask1 = df[['P/E_Cur', 'P/E_lag_1yr', 'P/E_lag_2yr', 'P/E_lag_3yr']].notnull().all(1)

mask2 = df['P/E_Cur'] > df[['P/E_lag_1yr', 'P/E_lag_2yr', 'P/E_lag_3yr']].max(1)

mask3 = (df['P/E_Cur'] / df['P/E_lag_3yr'] - 1) > 0.1

df['P/E_flag'] = np.where(mask1, np.where(mask2 & mask3, 1, 0), np.nan)
```

Comment: Mask 1 could be: `df.drop('Ticker', 1).notnull().all(1)`. I think also we could divide mask2 in two parts for readability. Other than that I think we are getting closer.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand you there. I think it looks better now. I did edit OP's first attempt as it was just too much of a mess.